# Get Jquery Toogle button value from inside a loop

Tags: jquery, toggle, togglebutton

I am trying to keep 3 toggle buttons in a php loop with attribute name filled with dynamic values.

[image]

By Using Jquery onclick event, I want to capture the title attribute. By code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .switch-toggle {
     width: 10em;
     }

  .switch-toggle label:not(.disabled) {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>
<div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
<input id="on" name="state-d" type="radio" checked="" title="A-101-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<label for="on" onclick="">ON</label>

<input id="na" name="state-d" type="radio" disabled checked="checked">
    <label for="na" onclick="">N/A</label>

<input id="off" name="state-d" type="radio" title="A-202-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<label for="off" onclick="">OFF</label>

<a></a>
</div>
<p></p>
<?php } ?>


</body>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".switch-candy input[type='radio']").click(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            alert(title);
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Whenever, I click on any button, I am getting only the 1st button attribute. I was unable to get the attributes for 2nd & 3rd toggle buttons.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you attach the rendered html code? and I would like to say you to remove id attr. because, your code will generate duplicated ids.

Comment: @TomaszBucko, If I remove the id attr, the toggle functionality is not working..

Comment: please check my answer. I tried to build html code based on your php code. and tested on chrome inspection console. and it's working.

Comment: for ids, I think it's not important. but it's not standard that same ids are existing in same page.

Comment: @TomaszBucko, I need that in a loop not in html code, Let me know if you have a working idea.

Comment: I can't understand you. PHP is server side language and code will be changed into common html code. and javascript will run in client side (browser). so your jquery code will work with common html code, not PHP code.

Comment: please let me know what you want exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` and `name` attributes on your buttons, this will make your HTML invalid and javascript will treat them as one radio button, so you have to add the current for loop counter to make the id attribute dynamic and prevent duplicate.

this is working HTML version:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .switch-toggle {
     width: 10em;
     }

  .switch-toggle label:not(.disabled) {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
<input id="on-0" name="state-d-0" type="radio" checked="" title="A-101-0">
<label for="on-0" onclick="">ON</label>

<input id="na-0" name="state-d-0" type="radio" disabled checked="checked">
    <label for="na-0" onclick="">N/A</label>

<input id="off-0" name="state-d-0" type="radio" title="A-202-0">
<label for="off-0" onclick="">OFF</label>

<a></a>
</div>
<p></p>
    <div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
<input id="on-1" name="state-d-1" type="radio" checked="" title="A-101-1">
<label for="on-1" onclick="">ON</label>

<input id="na-1" name="state-d-1" type="radio" disabled checked="checked">
    <label for="na-1" onclick="">N/A</label>

<input id="off-1" name="state-d-1" type="radio" title="A-202-1">
<label for="off-1" onclick="">OFF</label>

<a></a>
</div>
<p></p>
    <div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
<input id="on-2" name="state-d-2" type="radio" checked="" title="A-101-2">
<label for="on-2" onclick="">ON</label>

<input id="na-2" name="state-d-2" type="radio" disabled checked="checked">
    <label for="na-2" onclick="">N/A</label>

<input id="off-2" name="state-d-2" type="radio" title="A-202-2">
<label for="off-2" onclick="">OFF</label>

<a></a>
</div>
<p></p>


</body>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".switch-candy input[type='radio']").click(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            alert(title);
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

for `PHP` code it should be like this:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .switch-toggle {
         width: 10em;
         }

      .switch-toggle label:not(.disabled) {
       cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++): ?>
    <div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
    <input id="on-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="state-d-<?php echo $i; ?>" type="radio" checked="" title="A-101-<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <label for="on-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="">ON</label>

    <input id="na-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="state-d-<?php echo $i; ?>" type="radio" disabled checked="checked">
        <label for="na-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="">N/A</label>

    <input id="off-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="state-d-<?php echo $i; ?>" type="radio" title="A-202-<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <label for="off-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="">OFF</label>

    <a></a>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <?php endfor; ?>


    </body>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".switch-candy input[type='radio']").click(function(){
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                alert(title);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think the id is not matter for this current issue. as you can see my attached image, I tested with objects that have duplicated ids. but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make html code based on your php code as following.

[image]

and tested jQuery code in console as following
[image]

as you can see, it is working well.
my jquery code is as follwing

```
$(".switch-candy input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('title'))
})
```

but I think it's same with yours, please check again.

Comment: I did test it locally on my machine, my solution worked but yours still give same result as OP, not sure why I was downvoted (I'm not blaming you I even upvoted your answer though :P).

Comment: sorry for that. my younger brother did it. and when I try to revert, you deleted your answer :(

Comment: no wories, I will post my answer again, you can remove it :)

Comment: @ROOT, I have copied your code from the answer and it works for me, I have kept auto incrementing value <?php echo $i; ?> and it worked awesome. Thanks man, you saved my time.

Comment: OK. I will do it. :-D